# While reading json data from my document DB, I want to add some configuration using which part of json structure would be transformed into a pojo

Tags: java, json

I have to come up with a design, basically a configuration that I can pass to a Mongo Reader job, to convert the read document(json) to a flat json structure. for e.g.(excuse the made up e.g.). Idea is that the json can be of any structure, but i should be able to control the output of the reader based on my mapping that i provide to this job.

animal: {
dog: {
name: pluto,
age: 4
},
cat: {
name: mini,
age: 1
},
hamster: {
name: jack
age: 0.3
}
}

TO

animals: [{
type: dog,
name: pluto,
age: 4
}, {
type: cat,
name: mini,
age: 1
}, {
type: hamster,
name: jack,
age: 1
}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prepare utilities**

*Converters.java*

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.json.Converter;
import org.bson.json.JsonMode;
import org.bson.json.JsonWriterSettings;
import org.bson.json.StrictJsonWriter;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Converters {

    private Converters () {
    }

    private static class ObjectIdConverter implements Converter<ObjectId> {

        public static final Converters.ObjectIdConverter INSTANCE = new Converters.ObjectIdConverter();

        @Override
        public void convert(ObjectId value, StrictJsonWriter writer) {
            writer.writeString(value.toHexString());
        }
    }

    private static final JsonWriterSettings JSON_WRITER_SETTINGS = JsonWriterSettings
        .builder()
        .outputMode(JsonMode.RELAXED)
        .objectIdConverter(Converters.ObjectIdConverter.INSTANCE)
        .build();

    public static String bsonToJson(Document bson) {
        return bson == null ? null : bson.toJson(JSON_WRITER_SETTINGS);
    }

    public static String bsonListToJson(List<Document> bsonList) {
        return bsonList == null || bsonList.isEmpty() ? null :
            "[" + bsonList.stream()
                .map(Converters::bsonToJson)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) +
            "]";
    }
}
```

*JsonDao.java*

```
import org.bson.BsonDocument;
import org.bson.BsonValue;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.json.JsonReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class JsonDao {
    
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Document> findDocuments(String collectionName, String query, String projection) {
        return mongoTemplate.find(
            new BasicQuery(query, projection),
            Document.class,
            collectionName
        );
    }

    public List<Document> aggregateDocuments(String collectionName, String operations) {
        List<BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonArrayCodec()
            .decode(new JsonReader(operations), DecoderContext.builder().build())
            .stream()
            .map(BsonValue::asDocument)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public String findJsonString(String collectionName, String query, String projection) {
        return bsonToJson(mongoTemplate.findOne(
            new BasicQuery(query, projection),
            Document.class,
            collectionName
        ));
    }

    public String findJsonArrayString(String collectionName, String query, String projection) {
        return bsonListToJson(findDocuments(collectionName, query, projection));
    }

    public String aggregateJsonString(String collectionName, String operations) {
        List<Document> documents = aggregateDocuments(collectionName, operations);
        return documents.isEmpty() ? null : bsonToJson(documents.get(0));
    }

    public String aggregateJsonArrayString(String collectionName, String operations) {
        return bsonListToJson(aggregateDocuments(collectionName, operations));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.21'

-------------------------------------------------

String json = jsonDao.findJsonString(<collectionName>, <findOneQuery>, <projection>);
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(<transformationQuery>);
// Then use Jackson ObjectMapper to convert JsonNode to POJO
```

*Test transformation*

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
        "{\n" +
        "    \"animal\": {\n" +
        "        \"dog\": {\n" +
        "            \"name\": \"pluto\",\n" +
        "            \"age\": 4\n" +
        "        },\n" +
        "        \"cat\": {\n" +
        "            \"name\": \"mini\",\n" +
        "            \"age\": 1\n" +
        "        },\n" +
        "        \"hamster\": {\n" +
        "            \"name\": \"jack\",\n" +
        "            \"age\": 0.3\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "animal.map(animals: entries().map(type:key, name:value.name, age:value.age))");
System.out.println(node == null ? null : node.toPrettyString());
```

*Output*

```
{
  "animals" : [ {
    "type" : "dog",
    "name" : "pluto",
    "age" : 4
  }, {
    "type" : "cat",
    "name" : "mini",
    "age" : 1
  }, {
    "type" : "hamster",
    "name" : "jack",
    "age" : 0.3
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for a configuration rather than code. I want to make this piece configurable, so that i can flatten any json structure that I read from Mongo, based on my requirement.
I di find something interesting here https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt but I find its configuration a little too complex for my liking. was thinking if we can have something simple.

Comment: My coding is used to read any MongoDB document as JSON String. Not dedicated to specific data structure. Suitable for all cases. Then I use "Josson.fromJsonString()" to deserialize the JSON String. Again, this is suitable for all cases.

The dynamic and "configurable" part is the one and only one query statement which is:

josson.getNode("animal.map(animals: entries().map(type:key, name:value.name, age:value.age))");

that returns a JsonNode that hold the result of your example.

Comment: BTW, I used this method to build a notification template engine that is sending millions of SMS/Email/Push notifications per year. Reading MongoDB collections is configurable in a notification template which is also a MongoDB document. No addition and specific Java program is required for different notification. [link](https://www.josson.org) _Josson&Jossons_